# THREE.js GLTF Rendering Order

Tags: three.js, gltf

Please consider these two snippets - Same code, two different versions of three - `0.113.2` and the latest `0.147.0`. Move the camera to clearly see the issue.

Both are importing a GLTF, but it looks very wrong in `0.147.0`. I'm aware that the model itself is using transparent textures whose meshes all seem to have very similar if not the same position. Their bufferGeometries are very different.

**My question - What can I do to resolve the rendering order?** What would a good suggested approach be?

- I've tried sampling the buffer geometries of each mesh to determine the order (assumed from 0,0,0 for now), which is 'better', but not good.

Any ideas?

One using `0.113.2`:

```js
const GLTFLoader = THREE.GLTFLoader // CDN shim
const OrbitControls = THREE.OrbitControls // CDN shim

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000 )
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } )
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
renderer.setAnimationLoop( function(time) {
  controls.update()
  renderer.render( scene, camera )
})
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement )

const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement )
camera.position.set( 18776, 4888, -7446 )
window.onresize = function () {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
}
new GLTFLoader().load(
  'https://kujata-data-dg.netlify.app/data/battle/battle.lgp/opaa.hrc.gltf',
  (gltf) => {
      scene.add( gltf.scene )
  }
)

// Just to hide the GLTF warning log
window.console = (function (origConsole) {
  if (!window.console || !origConsole) {
    origConsole = {}
  }
  return {
    log: function () {
      origConsole.log.apply(origConsole, arguments)
    },
    warn: function () {
      if (arguments[0] !== 'THREE.GLTFLoader: Missing min/max properties for accessor POSITION.') {
        origConsole.warn.apply(origConsole, arguments)
      }
    },
    error: function () {
      origConsole.error.apply(origConsole, arguments)
    },
    info: function (v) {
      origConsole.info.apply(origConsole, arguments)
    }
  }
})(window.console)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.113.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.113.2/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.113.2/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
```

The other using the latest `0.147.0`:

```js
const GLTFLoader = THREE.GLTFLoader // CDN shim
const OrbitControls = THREE.OrbitControls // CDN shim

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000 )
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } )
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
renderer.setAnimationLoop( function(time) {
  controls.update()
  renderer.render( scene, camera )
})
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement )

const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement )
camera.position.set( 18776, 4888, -7446 )
window.onresize = function () {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
}
new GLTFLoader().load(
  'https://kujata-data-dg.netlify.app/data/battle/battle.lgp/opaa.hrc.gltf',
  (gltf) => {
      scene.add( gltf.scene )
  }
)

// Just to hide the GLTF warning log
window.console = (function (origConsole) {
  if (!window.console || !origConsole) {
    origConsole = {}
  }
  return {
    log: function () {
      origConsole.log.apply(origConsole, arguments)
    },
    warn: function () {
      if (arguments[0] !== 'THREE.GLTFLoader: Missing min/max properties for accessor POSITION.') {
        origConsole.warn.apply(origConsole, arguments)
      }
    },
    error: function () {
      origConsole.error.apply(origConsole, arguments)
    },
    info: function (v) {
      origConsole.info.apply(origConsole, arguments)
    }
  }
})(window.console)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.147.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've never encountered this problem before, but it sounds similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128095/threejs-gltf-alpha-mode-blend-option-does-not-work-at-some-angles) and [this discussion](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltfexporter-changing-alphamode/5993). Maybe those could help?

Comment: The important change between r113 and r147 was that `.depthWrite = false` is now set on all transparent materials in GLTFLoader. This improves rendering for surfaces that are _actually_ transparent, but can cause problems for surfaces marked as transparent that don't actually contain transparent pixels. Changing .depthWrite is a possible fix, but I think the solution below (marking materials OPAQUE where possible) is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research and trial and error I have generally mitigated this issue by:

- Interrogating each texture for each material, if the material DOES NOT contain transparent pixels (or within a threshold), I set the GLTF material to `alphaMode: 'OPAQUE'` (should be by default)
- If it DOES contain transparent pixels, I set the GLTF material to `alphaMode: 'BLEND'`

*Note: I'm generating these GLTFs from another non-GLTF source, so I'm not in control of the source geometry data. This seems to generally solve my main issues.*